# How set up MySQL and phpmyadmin on a docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need an example of setting up MySQL and phpmyadmin on a docker compose file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to setup username and password under environment in docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  my-db:
```

and for phpmyadmin, I had used a phpmyadmin image from docker hub:

```
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - 80:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: 'user'
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Added  [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) dependency into requirements.txt. required to allow Django to connect with MySQL.

In the Dockerfile, added the following into the Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7


ENV TZ=Africa/Nairobi
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone



ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# add requirements.txt to the image
ADD requirements.txt /app/

# set working directory to /app/
WORKDIR /app/


RUN pip install --upgrade pip


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Set up MYSQL configurations on django `settings.py`:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'django_mysql_docker',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysqladmin',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I added the following in the **docker-compose** file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      # - ./init-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./data-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqladmin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: django_mysql_docker
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'mysqladmin'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions
```

On the port :8082 (http://0.0.0.0:8082/) you will find phpmyadmin:

**phpMyAdmin Dashboard**

[image]